# Typo in Introduction to Smooth Manifolds - Lee?

Tags: reference-request

I believe I've found a typo in this text, but it's also possible that I'm not understanding the statement:

The statement is about transversality.  "Suppose $N,M,$ and $S$ are smooth manifolds and for each $s\in S$ we are given a map $F_s:N\rightarrow M$.  The collection $\{F_s|s\in S\}$ is called a smooth family of maps if the map $F:M\times S\rightarrow N$ defined by $F(x,s)=F_s(x)$ is smooth."

Shouldn't $F:N\times S\rightarrow M$?  Since $F_s:N\rightarrow M$ then $F(x,s)=F_s(x)$ means that $x\in N$, not $x\in M$... am i missing something or is this indeed a typo?  I am pretty confident that it's a typo, but since I'm no expert on the material, I want to make sure I'm not missing something...

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: Indeed, it should be $N$ instead of $M$.

Comment: @JoeJohnson126 thanks!

Comment: Good catch -- this is a mistake I hadn't noticed before. I've now added it to my [online correction list](http://www.math.washington.edu/~lee/Books/ISM/).

Answer (score 0):

You are right. It is a typo.${}$